# phpunit gives same response for multiple calls with different parameters

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i recently moved from laravel 5.2 to laravel 5.4. In 5.2 all testcases were working fine. After upgrading to new version i am facing issues with testcases. Below is my sample code that was working fine in 5.2.

```
    $params = [
        'id' => 'asddsdsd'
    ];

    $response1 = $this->call('GET', '/user/getInfo', $params);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('status', $response1);
    $this->assertTrue($response1['status'] == 400);

    $params2 = [
        'id' => '23'
    ];

    $response2 = $this->call('GET', '/user/getInfo', $params2);

    $this->assertArrayHasKey('status', $response2);
    $this->assertTrue($response2['status'] == 200);
```

in laravel 5.2 both used to have seperate response, in first case i used to get Failure response and second case, i was getting Success response.

After upgrading to 5.4, i am gettign same response for two testcases. Basically, the first call response is copied to second response because of calling same URl. This is happening for all the testcases.

Note: I added second case in different method, but still facing the same issue

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this??

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache with `$ php artisan cache:clear` yet, just in case?

Comment: yes i tried, but did not work

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->get('/user/getInfo', $params2);` instead of `$this->call('GET', '/user/getInfo', $params2);`?

Comment: tried now and not working. same issue

Comment: Does using `$this->refreshApplication()` in between the calls work? Not saying this is the final solution though...

Comment: $this->refreshApplication() this was working fine in 5.2. but in 5.4 this is not working

Comment: You might need to split the test case into 2 separate methods and then link them using a `depends`. I'll write up an example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `call()` method returns a [`Response` object in 5.2](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_call), but a [`TestResponse` object in 5.4](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_call). To make your code comparable in 5.4, you could try using the `baseResponse` property of your `TestResponse` object:

```
$this->assertArrayHasKey('status', $response1->baseResponse);
```

You might also need to separate your 2 requests into separate modular test cases and then link them using `@depends` annotation.

```
public function testRequest1()
{
    $params = [
        'id' => 'asddsdsd'
    ];

    $response1 = $this->call('GET', '/user/getInfo', $params);

    //$this->assertWhatever()

    return $dataIfYouWantIt
}

/**
 * @depends testRequest1
 */
public function testRequest2($dataIfYouWantIt)
{
    $params2 = [
        'id' => '23'
    ];

    $response2 = $this->call('GET', '/user/getInfo', $params2);

    //$this->assertWhatever()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. I already tried using different method. it still gives error.

Comment: i mean, it still gets data of first testcase

Comment: Oh right, OK, so no error message or anything. I assume this is using the TestCase class, right? I don't suppose you can disable caching altogether in your web server setup to make sure that's not a factor?

Comment: yes, this is pointing TestCase class. Cache is also not a issue

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to check the response from each call?

Comment: I know there's no specific error message, but it could perhaps be linked to [this issue with using `require_once`](https://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-testcase-tests-unable-to-make-multiple-call) with test cases?

Comment: OK, I updated the answer with a possible solution due to different return types of the `call()` method.

Comment: i tried with your updated code and still did not solve the issue. For second call, i am still getting same response. 

`$symfonyRequest = SymfonyRequest::create(
            $this->prepareUrlForRequest($uri), $method, $parameters,
            $cookies, $files, array_replace($this->serverVariables, $server), $content );`

// In below code something unusual is happening. When i check the //code in controller, for second request i am getting 'params of first' call

        `$response = $kernel->handle(
            $request = Request::createFromBase($symfonyRequest)
        );`

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. I can't see anything that would cause the problems from this sample. Did you work out a solution yet?

Comment: nope, i tried in different ways, but no luck. i will post here as soon as i find the fix

Comment: OK, I'll be really interested to see what you find out!